# Create a PDF from appMaker page without using googleDocs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation, google-app-maker

The app I'm working on returns some search results in tables and I like to create a PDF from those results keeping the table's header, title and everything and without using Google Docs. Is it possible? If yes how can I do it?

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to use google docs?  This might be important to know what other options will work for you.

Comment: first thank you for your answer , the reason is using google docs I will not get the exact page , with google docs i will creat a new documents and creat all the elements using the server side script in google app maker , and in my case the client want the exact same page like a picture or screen capture , except that my search results length isn't always the same , so sometimes (most of the time) we have to scroll down the table to see all the results , that why I can't do a screen capture directly .

Comment: This Q seems not to be related to App Maker, since AM doesn't provide such built-in functionality and you need take a look at some 3rd party libraries. You can add 3rd party js lib in AM in `App Settings -> External Resources -> JavaScript URLs`

Comment: You can try with jsPDF. I use it in a project and works great... https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/

Comment: thank you all for your answers , @Morfinismo i will try it thank you .